# How can I reliably check which value of my React useEffect()'s dependency array caused it to execute, when dealing with reference types?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following React `useEffect()` with a dependency array of multiple reference types, e.g. functions `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`.

How can I reliably check which of these values changed and caused the effect to execute? When logging the values, only the functions' contents are displayed - not IDs or memory addresses -, so it's not possible to determine which changed.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (route === "authenticated") {
      navigate(from, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [f1, f2, f3]);
```

Comment: You can create a `useWhyDidYouUpdate`  hook to check that, there are plenty of exemples / packages to do so :) ie: https://usehooks.com/useWhyDidYouUpdate/